# Discord Interactions validation java

Tags: java, encryption, discord

Im trying to make serverless discord bot using java 11. Discord [documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/receiving-and-responding#security-and-authorization) doesn't provide any example in terms of validating in java. I have found a [java library](https://github.com/NeilMadden/salty-coffee) that might be of help here, but I have little expertise in this field and my code always results in validation failed. Would someone point me what im doing wrong during this validation ?

```java
SecretKey key = Crypto.authKey(fromHex("<MY APPLICATION PUBLIC KEY>"));
String message = x_signature_timestamp + event.get("body");
boolean verified = Crypto.authVerify(key,message.getBytes(),fromHex(x_signature_ed25519));
```

and

```java
public static byte[] fromHex(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                    + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
    }
    return data;
}
```

im always getting this when adding interactions endopint url[image: discord appication interactions endopint]

response im sending:

```java
if (!verified){
    response = ApiGatewayResponse.builder()
             .withHeaders(headers)
             .withBody("validation failed")
             .withStatusCode(401)
             .build();
} else {
    response = ApiGatewayResponse.builder()
            .withHeaders(headers)
            .withBody(event.get("body").toString())
            .withStatusCode(200)
            .build();
}
return response;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With salty-coffee the required Ed25519 verification can be performed under Java (11)!

With the following test data a successful verification can be performed using *tweetnacl* and the NodeJS code you linked:

```js
const nacl = require('tweetnacl');

const PUBLIC_KEY = "9c7d775851a98ceb09a80928c1f8ff56706a0f5d91d841c72850fcd92e065b8f"; // 'APPLICATION_PUBLIC_KEY'

const signature = "99c4903df0b00ac32ba158db956ee39586adf05fea6be714055ac79a80bfd9dff59399b7da01ced95d0a252daee6bdb07e5f59cc546322bb779fd749b04f170c"; // req.get('X-Signature-Ed25519')
const timestamp = '202204091535'; // req.get('X-Signature-Timestamp')
const body = 'testmessage'; // req.rawBody

const isVerified = nacl.sign.detached.verify(
  Buffer.from(timestamp + body),
  Buffer.from(signature, 'hex'),
  Buffer.from(PUBLIC_KEY, 'hex')
);

console.log(isVerified); // true
```

The analog Java code with *salty-coffee* that allows successful verification is:

```java
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import software.pando.crypto.nacl.Crypto;
...
String PUBLIC_KEY = "9c7d775851a98ceb09a80928c1f8ff56706a0f5d91d841c72850fcd92e065b8f";

String signature = "99c4903df0b00ac32ba158db956ee39586adf05fea6be714055ac79a80bfd9dff59399b7da01ced95d0a252daee6bdb07e5f59cc546322bb779fd749b04f170c";
String timestamp = "202204091535";
String body = "testmessage";

boolean isVerified = Crypto.signVerify(
      Crypto.signingPublicKey(fromHex(PUBLIC_KEY)), 
      (timestamp + body).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), 
      fromHex(signature));

System.out.println(isVerified); // true
```

Note that the verification is to be done with [`Crypto.signVerify()`](https://github.com/NeilMadden/salty-coffee#public-key-signatures) and not with [`Crypto.authVerify()`](https://github.com/NeilMadden/salty-coffee#secret-key-authentication).

Answer (score 0):

above `fromHex` implementation didn't work for me

what worked was using

```
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter

fun fromHex(string: String) = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(string)

rest as described @Topaco
```